# Incrementing two different sized arrays with different indexes in SwiftUI ForEach

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach, increment

let's say I have 2 arrays:

- array1.count = 5
- array2.count = 3

I'm looping through all the elements in array1 like so

```
@State var array2Index

ForEach(0 ..< array1.count, idL \.self){index in

  SomeView(varName: array1[index])

//here I want to show a different view with array2 for every second item of array1

  if index % 2 == 0{
   OtherView(varName: array2[array2Index])
   //this is not possible however
   array2Index += 1
  }
```

I tried to create a function that returns a View with an incremented index for array2 but it increments before the main view is even displayed because "array2Index" is a @State variable

Comment: ForEach is not a for loop if you use it like one, i.e. with indices instead of data, it'll crash when you use the index supplied to the closure to look up the array because it'll be out of date when the array changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another variable.  Just do math with `index`:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    let varName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(varName)
    }
}

struct OtherView: View {
    let varName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(varName)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let array1 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Donut", "Egg"]
    let array2 = ["1", "2", "3"]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(array1.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            
            SomeView(varName: array1[index])
            
            //here I want to show a different view with array2 for every second item of array1
            
            if index % 2 == 0 {
                OtherView(varName: array2[index / 2])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: Result running in Simulator]